# Pthread data race that drives me crazy

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, gcc, pthreads

I posted a similar question to this one a few weeks ago where I had trouble finding the data race in my N-queens program using pthreads in C. [Why is my multithreaded C program not working on macOS, but completely fine on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906140/why-is-my-multithreaded-c-program-not-working-on-macos-but-completely-fine-on-l/70910101#70910101)

I got a few suggestions in the comments sections of the post and I really tried my best to make corrections based on them. I sat with the suggestions a few days, changed some parts but the data race persisted and I just cannot understand why. There are counters inside critical sections for the number of productions and consumptions. I feel completely blind when looking through the code and analyzing it, I'm aware that consumptions are too many but the synchronization around that code fragment *should* with my knowledge be correct, but obviously something's not right. External input would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I'm using and I'm not sure how to reduce its size to still reproduce the issue. I compile it with gcc (clang-1205.0.22.11) on macOS Monterey (12.1) using a MacBook Pro 2020 x86_64 architecture.

compile: `gcc -o 8q 8q.c*` 
run: `./8q <consumers> <N>`, NxN chess board, N queens to place 
parameters: `./8q 2 4` Enough to highlight the problem (should yield 2 solutions, but every other run yields 3+ solutions, i.e duplicate solutions exist 
note: running the program with `./8q 2 4` should give 2 solutions, 1820 productions and 1820 consumptions.

```c
#ifndef _REENTRANT
    #define _REENTRANT
#endif

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>


typedef struct stack_buf {
    int positions[8];
    int top;
} stack_buf;

typedef struct global_buf {
    int positions[8];
    int buf_empty;
    long prod_done;
    int last_done;
} global_buf;

typedef struct print_buf {
    int qpositions[100][8];
    int top;
} print_buf;

stack_buf queen_comb = { {0}, 0 };
print_buf printouts = { {{0}}, 0 };
global_buf global = { {0}, 1, 0, 0 };
int N; //NxN board and N queens to place
long productions = 0;
long consumptions = 0;

pthread_mutex_t buffer_mutex, print_mutex;
pthread_cond_t empty, filled;


/* ##########################################################################################
   ################################## VALIDATION FUNCTIONS ##################################
   ########################################################################################## */

/* Validate that no queens are placed on the same row */
int valid_rows(int qpositions[]) {
    int rows[N];
    memset(rows, 0, N*sizeof(int));
    int row;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        row = qpositions[i] / N;
        if (rows[row] == 0) rows[row] = 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/* Validate that no queens are placed in the same column */
int valid_columns(int qpositions[]) {
    int columns[N];
    memset(columns, 0, N*sizeof(int));
    int column;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        column = qpositions[i] % N;
        if (columns[column] == 0) columns[column] = 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/* Validate that left and right diagonals aren't used by another queen */
int valid_diagonals(int qpositions[]) {
    int left_bottom_diagonals[N];
    int right_bottom_diagonals[N];
    int row, col, temp_col, temp_row, fill_value, index;

    for (int queen = 0; queen < N; queen++) {
        row = qpositions[queen] / N;
        col = qpositions[queen] % N;
        
        /* position --> left down diagonal endpoint (index) */
        fill_value = col < row ? col : row; // closest to bottom or left wall
        temp_row = row - fill_value;
        temp_col = col - fill_value;
        index = temp_row * N + temp_col; // board position
        for (int i = 0; i < queen; i++) { // check if interference occurs
            if (left_bottom_diagonals[i] == index) return 0;
        }
        left_bottom_diagonals[queen] = index; // no interference

        /* position --> right down diagonal endpoint (index) */
        fill_value = (N-1) - col < row ? N - col - 1 : row; // closest to bottom or right wall
        temp_row = row - fill_value;
        temp_col = col + fill_value;
        index = temp_row * N + temp_col; // board position
        for (int i = 0; i < queen; i++) { // check if interference occurs
            if (right_bottom_diagonals[i] == index) return 0;
        }
        right_bottom_diagonals[queen] = index; // no interference
    }
    return 1;
}

/* ##########################################################################################
   #################################### HELPER FUNCTION(S) ####################################
   ########################################################################################## */

/* print the collected solutions  */
void print(print_buf printouts) {
    static int solution_number = 1;
    int placement;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&print_mutex);
    for (int sol = 0; sol < printouts.top; sol++) { // all solutions
        printf("Solution %d: [ ", solution_number++);
        for (int pos = 0; pos < N; pos++) {
            printf("%d ", printouts.qpositions[sol][pos]+1);
        } 
        printf("]\n");

        printf("Placement:\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) { // rows
            printf("[ ");
            placement = printouts.qpositions[sol][N-i];
            for (int j = (N-i)*N; j < (N-i)*N+N; j++) { // physical position
                if (j == placement) {
                    printf(" Q ");
                } else printf("%2d ", j+1);
            }
            printf("]\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_mutex);
}


/* ##########################################################################################
   #################################### THREAD FUNCTIONS ####################################
   ########################################################################################## */

/* entry point for each worker (consumer) workers will 
check each queen's row, column and diagonal to evaluate 
satisfactory placements */
void *eval_positioning(void *id) {
    long thr_id = (long)id;
    int qpositions[N]; // on stack (thread-private)
    
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
        while (global.buf_empty == 1) { // no element
            if (global.last_done) { // last done, no combinations left 
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
                pthread_cond_signal(&filled);
                return NULL;
            }
            if (global.prod_done) {
                global.last_done = 1;
                break;
            }
            pthread_cond_wait(&filled, &buffer_mutex);
        }

        memcpy(qpositions, global.positions, N*sizeof(int)); // copy to local scope
        global.buf_empty = 1;
        consumptions++;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty);
        
        if (valid_rows(qpositions) && valid_columns(qpositions) && valid_diagonals(qpositions)) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&print_mutex);
            memcpy(printouts.qpositions[printouts.top], qpositions, N*sizeof(int));  /* save for printing later */
            printouts.top++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_mutex);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* recursively generate all possible queen_combs */
void rec_positions(int pos, int queens) {
    if (queens == 0) { // base case
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
        while (global.buf_empty == 0) { // while production hasn't been consumed
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &buffer_mutex);
        }
        memcpy(global.positions, queen_comb.positions, N*sizeof(int));
        productions++;
        global.buf_empty = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&filled);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = pos; i <= N*N - queens; i++) {
        queen_comb.positions[queen_comb.top++] = i;
        rec_positions(i+1, queens-1);
        queen_comb.top--;
    }
}

/* binomial coefficient | without order, without replacement
8 queens on 8x8 board: 4'426'165'368 queen combinations */
void *generate_positions(void *arg) {
    rec_positions(0, N);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
    global.prod_done = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&filled); //wake all to 
    return NULL;
}

/* ##########################################################################################
   ########################################## MAIN ##########################################
   ########################################################################################## */

/* main procedure of the program */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("usage: ./8q <workers> <board width/height>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int workers = atoi(argv[1]);
    N = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (N < 2 || N > 8) {
        printf("Wrong input! 2 <= N <= 8\n");
        return 0;
    }

    struct timeval start, stop;
    double elapsed;
    pthread_t consumers[workers];
    pthread_t producer;

    printf("\n");
    
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    pthread_create(&producer, NULL, generate_positions, NULL);
    for (long i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
        pthread_create(&consumers[i], NULL, eval_positioning, (void*)i+1);
    }

    pthread_join(producer, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
        pthread_join(consumers[i], NULL);
        char id[2];
        sprintf(id, "%d", i+1);
        write(1, id, strlen(id));
        write(1, " done\n\n", 6);
    }

    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    elapsed = stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
    elapsed += (stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / (double)1000000;
    
    /* go through all valid solutions and print */
    print(printouts);
    
    printf("board: %dx%d, workers: %d (+1), exec time: %fs, solutions: %d\n", N, N, workers, elapsed, printouts.top);
    printf("productions:  %ld\nconsumptions: %ld\n", productions, consumptions);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [mre] and post accordingly. I'm voting to close for a lack of focus right now.

Comment: I explicitly wrote that I didn't know how to reduce the code provided. No need for such comments.

Comment: Writing _"I'm not sure how to reduce its size to still reproduce the issue"_ is just lazy. Example: `long thr_id = (long)id;` why is that in your [mre]?

Comment: Oh well, you are right according to the link you're providing but I was "lazy" since I didn't believe these redundant *lines* were of importance. The main building blocks of the program has to be there (I believe) and therefore I did not put time and effort into changing details. I will try better next time though, don't get me wrong.

Comment: The art of creating **minimal** reproducible examples is the capability to remove noise while preserving the actual problem. The example I gave what just a minor part of your program that could be removed. I chose that part because the compiler told me it wasn't even used. _"I did not put time and effort into changing details"_ - Ok, you got a good answer this time even though you didn't do the work but I suggest that you put some effort into it the next time and then your question will get attention from more people.

Comment: This got me interested, are you saying that you took my code and compiled it but then "refused" to answer me due to the lack of focus on the actual problem? I'm getting more and more convinced of starting to actually do MRE to its full potential instead of getting a little lazy during the process. It is not my intention to scare people away ;)

Comment: Q1: _"are you saying that you took my code and compiled it but then "refused" to answer"_ - Yes
Q2: ? _"I'm getting more and more convinced of starting to actually do MRE to its full potential instead of getting a little lazy during the process. It is not my intention to scare people away ;)_" - You need to work on asking actutal questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initializing your mutexes and condition variables. The result is UB when used in pthread APIs. Two ways to do this, the simplest is just use the proper initializer:

```
pthread_mutex_t buffer_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t print_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t empty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t filled = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Unrelated, but worth mentioning, the `last_done` ideology is not necessary. This can be done with just the buf_empty and prod_done states. Specifically:

```
void *eval_positioning(void *tid)
{
    int qpositions[N]; // on stack (thread-private)

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);

        // while still producing *and* the buffer is empty
        while (!global.prod_done && global.buf_empty)
            pthread_cond_wait(&filled, &buffer_mutex);

        // if both are true, we're done. nothing to process, and
        //  there never will be (e.g. prod_done)
        if (global.prod_done && global.buf_empty)
        {
            // signal anyone else waiting on that mutex+cvar
            pthread_cond_signal(&filled);
            break;
        }

        // if we have a buffer to process (even if prod_done is true)
        else if (!global.buf_empty)
        {
            // make local copy of buffer
            memcpy(qpositions, global.positions, sizeof qpositions);
            ++consumptions;

            // mark global buffer as ready-to-receive
            global.buf_empty = 1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&empty);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);

            // if validated...
            if (valid_rows(qpositions) && valid_columns(qpositions) && valid_diagonals(qpositions))
            {
                // record and bump the printout counter.
                pthread_mutex_lock(&print_mutex);
                int row = printouts.top++;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_mutex);

                // this need not be protected by the mutex. we "own"
                //  this now, and can just blast away.
                memcpy(printouts.qpositions[row], qpositions, sizeof qpositions);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
        }
    }

    // make sure we unlock this
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);

    return tid;
}
```

With proper initialization of the concurrency materials, and the above eval processor, this is the consistent output:

**Output**

```
1 done
2 done
Solution 1: [ 2 8 9 15 ]
Placement:
[ 13 14  Q 16 ]
[  Q 10 11 12 ]
[  5  6  7  Q ]
[  1  Q  3  4 ]

Solution 2: [ 3 5 12 14 ]
Placement:
[ 13  Q 15 16 ]
[  9 10 11  Q ]
[  Q  6  7  8 ]
[  1  2  Q  4 ]

board: 4x4, workers: 2 (+1), exec time: 0.013001s, solutions: 2
productions:  1820
consumptions: 1820
```

<sub>Apologies for the puny laptop performance numbers</sub>

Comment: Wow this blows my mind, I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that initializers were redundant and simply there sometimes for readable code. I even recall my teacher at uni saying this...

Comment: Your teacher needs a refresher course in coding practices. as you originally had it, the aforementioned objects *are* "initialized" in one sense: they're static linkage (in this case, they're globals) so they're zero-filled. It just so happens in this case that is *not* what your platform indicates as a properly prepared initial configuration for a mutex, a cond-var, or both. Use your initializers or call the pthread_objtype_init methods per the posix specs. They're there for a reason.